# Can't add .wsdl in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, wsdl

Can't seem to add this web service in visual studio 2010 - what happens is :

```
C:\>wsdl [http://opensearch.addi.dk/1.0/opensearch.wsdl]

Error: Unable to import binding 'osSearchServiceSoapBinding' from namespace 'http://oss.dbc.dk/ns/opensearch_wsdl'.
- Unable to import operation 'search'.
- Group 'elementsAndRefinementsGroup' from targetNamespace='http://purl.org/dc/terms/' has invalid definition: Circular group reference.
```

I don't know much about this type of Web Services (use REST), but the guys that made this service use PHP and didn't see a problem or couldn't explain it to me.

I have look over the [.xsd files](http://oss.dbc.dk/websvn/listing.php?repname=Web+Services&path=%2FOpenSearch%2Ftags%2F1.0%2F&#a37f0504eda8490357d60938e78a906cb) but find them to verbose.

There is som PHP code in there but I do C# for the most part so I can't find heads or tails in them either.

Now the question is: How can I get this to work ? - if its not possible to fix so that I can import this in VS can someone show me how to do it manually in C#?

Answer (score 1):

The wsdl from the opensearch is not very Visual Studio friendly. There is, as you mention, a circular reference in the schema. I am doing an .NET implementation of this for another library (AALBIB) - i downloaded all the .xsd files and manually edited the circular reference out, hoping that i will never use that part of the system. Then generated proxy classes using thewsdl tool